# Usage of 'do' in ' ..."do" not only give information,they also...'

Tags: grammar

> Advertisements **do** not only give information,they also try to influence our emotions.

In this sentence, what is the usage of 'do'?

Comment: Three words I can think of to describe the use of ***do*** in the cited example are ***inappropriate, superfluous,*** and ***non-idiomatic***. [Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+not+only%2Cthey+do+not+only&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthey%20not%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthey%20do%20not%20only%3B%2Cc0) a chart showing how rarely we include [do-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) in such contexts.

Comment: I'd prefer ...are not only giving..., they are also trying to...

Comment: @user178049, there is no need at all to use present continuous. This sentence describes **something that is always true**, and present simple is perfectly adequate for that. If you want to brush up on your tense usage, check out this link: http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-simple

Answer (score 2):

> Advertisements **do** not only give information,they also try to influence our emotions.

As it stands, this is a strange sentence- half way between two satisfactory ways of expressing the meaning. Do is intended to negate the word **give**, but it is not actually necessary when used in **not only... but also..** construction:

> Advertisements **not only** give information, **but also** try to influence our emotions.

The **do** would be required if you used **just** instead of **only**: without the **non only.. but also**, the first part of the sentence is a completely independent clause, and you just negate the verb in the usual way:

> Advertisements **don't** just give information: they also try to influence our emotions.

I would be interested to know the source of the quote: my impression is that the writer was distracted half-way though changing from one form of words to the other.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in school, we called it a "helping verb".  It doesn't have a specific meaning by itself, it's part of a two-word verb.